# Make a particular column of a longtable borderless

Tags: tables, longtable

I am using longtable package to create tables as the number of rows are large and doesn't fit in a single page. This works fine for me. I now need a particular column not to have top and bottom border lines..

Example table which fits my requirement

```
 _________________       ___________    
|SlNum |Name      |Phone| Hobby     |
 -----------------       -----------
|   1  |Pitbull   | NA  | Raps a lot|
 ------------------      -----------
```

Comment: You can use `\cline` or `\cmidrule` if using `booktabs`. Welcome.

Comment: * [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\def\MyLine{\cline{1-2}\cline{4-4}}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{| l | l | c | l |}\MyLine
SlNum & Name   & Phone & Hobby     \\\MyLine
   1  & Pitbull& NA    & Raps a lot\\\MyLine
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, a good looking table is something different ...

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me. Yeah I know this is not a good looking table :)